# mysql command line stuck on "->"

Tags: mysql, command-line, mysql-8.0

I'm trying to learn how to use mysql from the command line but I'm running into problems. Typing a simple `SHOW VARIABLES` results in me getting a `->` prompt and no output:

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES
    -> █
```

I'm running mysql 8.0.26 on a MacBook Pro with Big Sur 11.6.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: TYPO You have to terminate all SQL commands in the command line with a semi colon `;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't ended your statement - mysql statements end with a semicolon

i.e.

```
SHOW VARIABLES;
```

Edit: Good point by IMSoP below. To expand: When you haven't completed your statement using a semicolon, the statement can continue on subsequent lines - mysql is not sensitive to white space or line breaks. The prompt will change to indicate mysql is still waiting for the rest of the statement, as in the table below [(Source)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/entering-queries.html)

| Prompt | Meaning |
| --- | --- |
| mysql> | Ready for new query |
| -> | Waiting for next line of multiple-line query |
| '> | Waiting for next line, waiting for completion of a string that began with a single quote (') |
| "> | Waiting for next line, waiting for completion of a string that began with a double quote (") |
| `> | Waiting for next line, waiting for completion of an identifier that began with a backtick (`) |
| /*> | Waiting for next line, waiting for completion of a comment that began with /* |

Comment: To explain why this gives the result seen, I believe the `->` is a "continuation prompt", waiting for *the next part of a multi-line statement*. I can't actually find a description of it in the MySQL manual, though.